# Why doesn't printing value out of array's bounds give me an error

Tags: c++

I made an array with 10 rows and 2 columns. Then I tried to access the element at the 100th row and 100th column. Why does this not give me an error:

```
#include <iostream>

int main () {
    int (*myarr)[2] = new int[10][2]();
    std::cout << myarr[100][100];
}
```

Comment: Because that's the way the language is. You get undefined behaviour instead. Your code *is* an error.

Comment: The behavior is undefined. C++ implementations are not required to detect out-of-bounds array accesses.

Comment: Because this is not java

Answer (score 0):

That would result in an undefined behavior. That means you could get a crash OR your program won't do anything.

Standard never said that you must get crash for that.